# SourceTree automatically updates StoryBoard

Tags: ios, xcode, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have an app which is done in `Objective-C` and is loaded by `bitBucket`, I have successfully added and modified codes and my friend who is connected to me in sourceTree is getting the updates that i do in my `xcode` class files. But when it comes to modification of the `storyboard` it automatically updates the storyBoard in my friend's mac who is connected to me only with bitbucket account, without any permission from me to commit changes in the storyboard. Please help me prevent the automatic updation of the storyboard by the sourceTree. Happy coding.

Comment: why don't you want to update storyboard changes?

Comment: you can add it to .gitignore file, but i don't see a purpose

Comment: I want to update the changes, but it is not even asking me for any confirmation. Even before committing the storyboard is getting updated. When my friend is working on his storyboard those changes are updated to mine immediately.

Comment: it is weird, it can not be because of source tree. look similar as you're sharing icloud directory.